# Determine Number of Midnights From Date Range

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have a reservation system, which charges a daily rate for overnights. I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the number of times midnight has been crossed for a given date range in PHP.

I have 2 unix timestamps:

```
$start_date        = 1404349200; // 07/02/14 07:00:00 pm
$end_date          = 1404936000; // 07/09/14 02:00:00 pm
$total_time_here   = $end_date - $start_date; // number of seconds here
$number_overnights = (int) ($total_time_here / 60 / 60 / 24); // calculate number of 24-hour periods
```

`$number_overnights` evaluates to `6`, however the number of times midnight occurred for that date range is `7`, which is what I want to count. This happens when the `$start_date` happens later in the day than the `$end_date` (7:00pm vs 2:00pm).

Both the `$start_date` and `$end_date` are in the same time zone, and are stored in UTC in the database and then converted back in PHP.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just check to see if the $start_date happens later in the day than the $end_date. If so, add 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work:

```
$start_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', 1404349200));
$end_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', 1404936000));
$total_time_here   = $end_date - $start_date;
$number_overnights = (int) ($total_time_here / 60 / 60 / 24);
```